# Capybara not finding submit button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

During an `rspec`-test, I am attempting to reset my password by filling a form and clicking the "Reset Password" link.

Capybara gives me the following error:

```
1) ResetPasswords emails user a reset link when resetting password
   Failure/Error: click_link 'Reset Password'
   Capybara::ElementNotFound:
     Unable to find link "Reset Password"
```

Apparently it does not find the link I want it to click. But when I attempt to print the page on which it is looking with `puts page.body`, this element is present:

```
<div><input name="commit" type="submit" value="Reset Password" /></div>
```

I've attempted to use `click`, `click_button` and `click_link`, but no cigar.

Why is the element not being found?

**Update 1: `click_button` output**

```
1) ResetPasswords emails user a reset link when resetting password
   Failure/Error: click_button 'Reset Password'
   ActionView::Template::Error:
     Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set
     default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
```

**Update 2: Test file**

```
require 'spec_helper'

include Warden::Test::Helpers
Warden.test_mode!

describe "ResetPasswords" do
  it "emails user a reset link when resetting password" do
    visit login_path
    click_link 'password'

    fill_in 'Email', :with => @user.email

    puts page.body
    click_link 'Reset Password'

    page.should have_content "You will receive an email"
  end

  before(:each) do
    @user = create(:user)
    #login_as @user, :scope => :user
  end
end
```

Comment: What is the output given by `click_button 'Reset Password'` method?

Comment: As you can see, it finds the Email field and fills it properly, I have confirmed this. Yet, it does not know how to submit the form..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting this snippet into `config/environments/test.rb` solved it:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => "localhost:3000"}
```

Answer (score 0):

try going directly to page for reset password

```js
describe "ResetPasswords" do
  it "emails user a reset link when resetting password" do
    visit reset_password_path

    fill_in 'Email', :with => @user.email

    click_link 'Reset Password'

    page.should have_content "You will receive an email"
  end

  before(:each) do
    @user = create(:user)
    #login_as @user, :scope => :user
  end
end
```